# SQLite - integer PRIMARY INDEX constraint failing?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

In my Android app, I create a **FULLTEXT** table like this:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE products USING fts3 (
    _id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    product_name text NOT NULL,
   ...
)
```

And I add this index:

```
CREATE INDEX product_name_index ON products (product_name)
```

The app populates the table with various products, each with a unique `_id` value.

However, when I then try to insert an already-existing product ID (using an `_id` value that is already in the table, but with a different `product_name` value) like this:

`long rowId = db.insertOrThrow("products", null, contentValues);`

a ***new*** row is added to the table (with a brand new `rowId` value returned)!

I expected the `insertOrThrow` command to fail, so where am I going wrong? Is it something to do with the fact that it's a FULLTEXT table or could the index I specified on the `product_name` column be messing things up somehow?

I read this section about [INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid), but unfortunately I'm none the wiser.

**Update**

When I try to perform the same operation on a standard (non-FULLTEXT) table, then the `insertOrThrow` command results in the expected `SQLiteConstraintException`.

Comment: I suggest you to use Room, which has an annotation called `@PrimaryKey(autogenerate = true)` which never allows you to have full control on the unique Index.

Comment: @Shawn The `null` value is the **nullColumnHack** argument, which - according to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#insertOrThrow(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues) - is not applicable here as `contentValues` is not empty. Plus, like I added in my update, I'm not getting this problem for non-FULLTEXT tables. If I'm misunderstanding something, could you post an answer with more explanation.

Comment: And why the downvote (whoever left it)? The question is clear and shows research effort...

Comment: Ah-ha. I really should have gone back and [read the FTS3 documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) before commenting. [Section 1.2](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#creating_and_destroying_fts_tables) in particular will be of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue might be that an FTS table has the concept of a **docid** and a **rowid** column and specifying null for the **docid** results in that being given a value.

as per :-

> There is one other subtle difference between "docid" and the normal
> SQLite aliases for the rowid column.
>
> Normally, if an INSERT or UPDATE
> statement assigns discrete values to two or more aliases of the rowid
> column, SQLite writes the rightmost of such values specified in the
> INSERT or UPDATE statement to the database.
>
> However, assigning a
> non-NULL value to both the "docid" and one or more of the SQLite rowid
> aliases when inserting or updating an FTS table is considered an
> error. See below for an example.

[1.3. Populating FTS Tables](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#populating_fts_tables)

Comment: Thanks, @MikeT. I have it sorted now. All I needed to do, when updating or inserting into the table, was to extend my `contentValues` entries - basically creating a new `docid` entry that holds the same value from the existing `_id` entry.